# Byte order conversion with mysql native function

Tags: c++, mysql, c, endianness

I've read in 4 bytes binary string from a file. The 4 bytes binary string is big endian, and represents a 32-bit integer. But My machine is little endian (intel). So I need to convert the 4 bytes binary string of big endian into 32-bit little endian integer.

Is there any native function in mysql could handle this? An example will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

**Update:**
OS dependent function or c/c++ standard library is highly restricted in mysql project and could hardly be used in this case.

Comment: C, C++ or SQL, what do you need?

Comment: @alk "I need to convert the 4 bytes string of big endian into 32-bit little endian integer" in mysql source code with C.

Comment: I wonder why you tag this C or C++ if there "tools" can not be used.

Comment: As far as I know there is no SQL function to do what you want. You might like to set up your own stored procedure using MySQL-SQL.

Comment: @alk Because the mysql source code is in c/c++.

Comment: Isn't this irrelevant if the issue may not be solved on C/C++ level?

Comment: @alk I am not asking about anything about SQL. The native function of mysql are all int c/c++.

Comment: @alk It is on C/C++ level, along with mysql API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C you can use `ntohl()` to convert 32bit (that is 4 bytes) integers to host byte order.

Its prototype should reside in `<arpa/inet.h>`.

**Update**

The `ntoh/hton` family of functions is defined by the POSIX standard.

It converts network byte order to host bytes order and verse visa.

Network byte order is defined to be Big Endian.

Comment: OS dependent function or c/c++ standard library is highly restricted in mysql project. It could hardly be used in my case. I want more suggestions with mysql native function. Thanks anyway, for the effort.

Comment: I think I'd better write my own. Your answer is accepted, cause it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert 32-bit little endian raw integer data  starting at offset `N` in column `s` into a decimal like this:

```
conv(hex(reverse(substr(s, N + 1, 4))), 16, 10)
```

I found this page looking for a more efficient way to do it without writing a UDF. With a UDF is it is simple and very efficient - you can do it by hand without any library calls, but, you have to know C, and you have to have enough access to the server to be able to install the UDF, which would be impossible on something like Amazon RDS or Aurora.